# Facebook graph api started to return only the first 10 posts in a group feed

Tags: facebook-graph-api, feed

a few days ago I started to experience troubles accessing facebook group data feed using graph api (i am using v2.8 but the results are the same also with older versions).

The graph api call started to return only the first 10 posts in the feed (i.e. the most recent ones) even though no changes were made from my side.

The same behaviour is reproducible also in graph api explorer using /groupId/feed path (I am not passing the 'limit' parameter in the request url). Previously it has been returning all the available posts with paging, etc.

Please note that if I use a pageId instead of groupId all the posts in the specified page are returned correctly - seems only groups are affected.

Can somebody shed some light on this?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to [this thread](https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/permalink/1216228635087315/) in Facebook Developer Community it looks like a bug.

Here are bug reports:

1. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1316646108368355?hc_location=ufi
2. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1796973007211974?hc_location=ufi
3. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1645827285730392?hc_location=ufi